# How to set a values inside a custom function

Tags: function-construction

I have a custom function like this

```
stringLength[string_] := 
 StringLength[
  ToExpression[StringJoin[ToString /@ {del, string}]] = 
   StringDelete[string, " "]]
```

I hope when the function return the string's length and set its value to a new symbol simultaneously.But actually this action is forbided in `Mathematica`

```
rand = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9";
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So how to implement this demand?

---

**The return is `9` and the `delrand` is "123456789"(no whitespace) in my expected.**

---

As the @m_goldberg and the @RunnyKine's help,I update my custom function to this

```
Clear["`*"]
SetAttributes[stringLength, HoldFirst]
stringLength[string_] := 
 StringLength[
  Evaluate[ToExpression["del" <> ToString@Unevaluated[string]]] = 
   StringDelete[string, " "]]
rand = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9";
{stringLength[rand], delrand} // FullForm
```

> List[9,"123456789"]

And I understand the `HoldFirst` this time,thanks you both.Don't closing this post please,and this two post have some difference still.That post just change the parameter's value,but my post have also change the parameter itself.Furthermore,there are @m_goldberg and the @RunnyKine's efforts in follow.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @RunnyKine When I run my custom function,then "return the string's length and set its value to del<stringname> simultaneously".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a somewhat more general but still more concise version of RunnyKine's answer.

```
SetAttributes[stringLength, {HoldFirst}]
stringLength[s_Symbol, prefix_String] :=
  With[{nowhite = StringDelete[s, Whitespace]}, 
    StringLength[Evaluate[Symbol[prefix <> SymbolName[Unevaluated[s]]]] = nowhite]]

Clear[delrand]; {stringLength[rand, "del"], delrand}
```

> `{9, "123456789"}`

Comment: Good solution,And we can set a default like `prefix_String: "del"`.

Comment: I'm confuse that why the `delrand` I get is [a Integer](http://i.stack.imgur.com/W2mQS.png)?

Comment: @yode. Have you looked at it with `FullForm`?

Comment: Ok,when I restart the kernel,that's normal.

Comment: Can you explain that why we should `Unevaluated[s]` when set the function `HoldFirst`?In my understanding,the `HoldFirst` is enough.

Comment: @yode. Well, you are wrong. `HoldFirst` is only in force at argument evaluation time, which is before the function body is called. Inside the body. `s` will evaluated normally unless it is protected. If that were not true, then the assignment to `nowhite` would not work correctly -- it depends on the value of `s`.

Answer (score 3):

Start by giving your function the `HoldFirst` `Attribute`.

```
SetAttributes[stringLength, {HoldFirst}]
```

The following should do what you want. Note that the left hand side of `Set` (`=`) is not evaluated, so we have to force it to evaluate by using `Evaluate`:

```
stringLength[string_] := 
 With[{res = StringDelete[string, " "]}, 
   (Evaluate @ Symbol["del" <> SymbolName[Unevaluated@string]] = res; 
    StringLength @ res)]
```

Now we can get the desired behavior when we call this function:

```
rand = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9";
stringLength[rand]
```

> 9

```
delrand
```

> "123456789"

Comment: Oh,The `delrand` should be `123456789`(no whitespace)

Comment: Oh,Sorry my English,your answer help me still,But the return is `9` and the `delrand` is `123456789` in my expected.

Comment: @yode. See my update

Comment: Good job.thanks a lot.:)

Comment: Sorry,I should give a thought to accept it.Maybe there are better solutions to do this.

Comment: @yode. It's okay to wait before accepting.

Comment: I'm very grateful your edit over and over again.But this answer can help everyone still.Feel so sorry to you.